# Differentiability of $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{cos(ax)-1}{x^{2}} ,x<0 \\ a+x, x\geq 0\end{cases}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've to find the values of $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x)$ is differentiable:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{cos(ax)-1}{x^{2}}  ,x<0 \\ a+x, x\geq 0\end{cases}$

I found that it is continuous for $a=-2$ or $ a=0$ and that $f(0)=a$

Then I tried to study differentiability whith this limit 
$lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{\frac{cos(a(a+h))-1}{(a+h)^{2}} -a}{h}$

and I looked for values of $a$ for which the limit is equal to $1$ but I found that the limit goes to $\infty$

Whereas if I differentiate the function and do the limit of $f'$ I get

$lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{-a x sin(ax)-2cos(ax)+2}{x^{3}}=0$

Where is my mistake? The two limits should give the same value!

Comment: Note that in the first equation you're sending $x \to a^-$, while in the second to $0^-$, and there's no reason for the limits to be same (except if you're explicitly considering the $a = 0$ case). The $a+h$ is incorrect, it should be just $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the choice $a=0$ you have 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\ge 0\\x&x<0\end{cases}$$
which isn't differentiable at $x=0$.

For the choice of $a=-2$
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(h)}{2h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\cos (-2 )-1}{h^2}-(-(a+h))}{2h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^3+2 h^2+\cos (2 h)-1}{2 h^3}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3h^2+4h-2\sin (2 h)}{6 h^2}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{6h+4-4\cos (2 h)}{12 h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{6+8\sin (2 h)}{12 }=\frac{1}{2}
$$